# Is it possible for rails to save multiple data type in same db column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to simulate variable_set and variable_get in drupal which use as site-wide variables storage. I tried something like this.

```
# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20091212170012
#
# Table name: variables
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  value      :text
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

class Variable < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :value

  validates_uniqueness_of :name
  validates_presence_of :name, :value


  def self.set(name, value)
    v = Variable.new() 
    v.name = name
    v.value = value
    v.save
  end  

  def self.get(name)
    Variable.find_by_name(name).value
  end

end
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to do this using yaml for storing your values as encoded strings.

Since I'm not storing the "values" on the database, but their converstions to strings, I named the column `encoded_value` instead of `value`.

`value` will be a "decoder-getter" method, transforming the yaml values to their correct types.

```
class Variable < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :name

  validates_presence_of :name, :encoded_value #change in name

  def self.set(name, value)
    v = Variable.find_or_create_by_name(name) #this allows updates. name is set.
    v.encoded_value = value.to_yaml #transform into yaml
    v.save
  end  

  def self.get(name)
    Variable.find_by_name(name).value
  end

  def value() #new method
    return YAML.parse(self.encoded_value).transform
  end

end
```

This should return integers, dates, datetimes, etc correctly (not only raw strings). In addition, it should support Arrays and Hashes, as well as any other instances that correctly define `to_yaml`.

Comment: This is exactly what I looking for the whole week. million thanks :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. By the way, I realized that the name was already set by the find_or_create call - you can remove it if you want.

Comment: Where do you know these YAML.parse().transform I can't see it in rails doc.

Comment: Problem found on array and hash. It said instance of IO needed

Comment: It is because I declared serialize :value, but don't know why this cause a problem.

Comment: I actually didn't look in the documentation, just used the console. Wrote YAML.[TAB]. Found the parse method. Then tried YAML.parse(1.to_yaml), and it gave me a weird object. Assigned it to a variable called x. Then wrote x.[TAB] and found the transform method.

I believe that YAML isn't rails. It's ruby: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/YAML.html

Regarding serialize... well it *should* work as you wrote in your question. But for some reason it is not - try removing the serialize line, and let's see what it gives you

Answer (score 0):

I have the following in one of my applications :

```
class Configure < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.get(name)
        value = self.find_by_key name
        return value.value unless value.nil?
        return ''
    end

    def self.set(name, value)
        elem= self.find_by_key name

        if elem.nil?
            #We add a new element
            elem = Configure.new
            elem.key = name
            elem.value = value
            elem.save!
        else
            #We update the element
            elem.update_attribute(:value, value)
        end
        return elem.value
    end
end
```

Which is apparently what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes this what is I tried to do, but the problem is the value returned is always a string. Do I need to parse it myself ?

Comment: Well yeah. You store the data as a string. It'll always be returned as a string.

Comment: I see that. I tried using Marshal.dump and Marshal.load for reserve its data type, but it failed when saving in sqlite for some reason "unrecognized token". I think because after marshal the format is like /004/blablabla and these /number are converted to unknown symbol that not recognized in sqlite. Do you have solutions for this ? or a parameter to save it as /number not alien symbol.

Thanks,